# Download SVGs rendered by React

Tags: reactjs, svg, shadow-dom

I would like to implement an export function on my SPA, consisting on generating a bunch of SVGs (generated using React JSX) and downloading them one at once.

The number of files being huge, I can't display them at the same time on the browser. I have found [React Download SVG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-download-svg) which permits to download a SVG which is already inthe DOM.

However, the render pipeline of React does not enable me to batch the downloading because I don't control the display cycle of my JSX SVG.

How could I download all my SVGs (zipping them in a file would be an advantage) without displaying them ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with similiar problem - generate parametrized SVG paths for CNC purpose.

Problem wasn't with download as invoked manually (after DOM update) - batch download (zipped) planned, also.

Problem was: **how to display SVG source/xml in another node/component for debugging** - updated on every parameter change.

> However, the render pipeline of React does not enable me to batch the downloading because I don't control the display cycle of my JSX SVG.

This is true ... is nome sense, even harder while React Fiber can delay some DOM updates - but **we have some possibilities** to be notified.

1. **componentDidUpdate**() - but 'not called for the initial render'
2. **ref callback** - but '... defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element'

I prefer 2nd method for a few reasons, f.e. neutral to SVG (functional) component internals - however it's not guaranteed to be called in every use case - it won't be if not needed - OTOH CDM and CDU are guaranteed to have updated/proper refs when called.

Another hint found somewhere (SO?): **use `setTimeout` to be safe/sure callback called after DOM update**.

```
downloadableReference = el => { 
  console.log("DWNLD_REF ",el); 
  this.svgElement = el        // save in wrapper, prevent old ref usage
  if( !!el ) {   // not null - second pass, fresh, updated
    console.log("DWNLD_REF ready ", el.outerHTML )
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      this.notifyDownloadableDependants()  // safest way - will be called after CDU
    }, 0 )
  } 
}
```

This can be combined to batch the downloading. For UX I would render them sequentially - with progress visualisation, cancellable processing etc.

Another possibility: - maybe (not tested) use of [react-jsx-parser](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser) be helpfull?